# Jfrog Pipelines - Step failing with "All resource versions are not fetched"

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

One of my steps suddenly started failing with the error:

> reqKick|executeStep|step|prepData|jFrogPipelinesSessionId:28be9c21-4ad6-4e3d-9411-7b9988535fd1|_getResourceVersions,
> All resource versions are not fetched. Requested resource versions: 16; received resource versions: []

Not sure what went wrong, I'd just reset my input resource.
How can I get my step back to working state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the resource were reset after the run was triggered. This scenario can happen.

Re-running the pipeline should work as expected.

Because when a resource is reset, it wipes out the resource version history and resets it to a single version, which is now considered the latest. This version is used for the new run. As the resource reset happened after the run was triggered, you faced the above error.